# Select radio button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select the radio button 'Government & Military' on [this](http://www.marriott.com/search/default.mi) page using Selenium.

The code below tries two different methods, but neither are working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Joe/Python/chromedriver')

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="propertygov"]').click()
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="propertygov"]')[0].click()
```

Edit:

Here is the full code. The initial interaction with the date form is keeping me from selecting the radio select:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Joe/Python/chromedriver')
browser.get("http://www.marriott.com/search/default.mi")

browser.find_element_by_id('editsearch-location').send_keys('Atlanta, GA')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hotel-fromDate"]').click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hotel-fromDate_table"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hotel-fromDate_table"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div').click()

browser.find_element_by_id('propertygov').click()
```

Comment: If you have the id why are you using find by xpath? try find_element_by_id('propertygov')

Comment: I just tried that and it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```python
browser.get("http://www.marriott.com/search/default.mi")
browser.find_element_by_id('propertygov').click()
```

Comment: Yeah just realized he was not hitting the url

Comment: This does work. I should have posted my full code. I think the problem is that my initial interaction with the date form is interfering with me being able to select the radio button.